# Where is the compression happening with Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

If you have a pipeline with a copy data activity, which copies data from an on-prem SQL server to an azure data lake storage account - and you choose some form of compression.

**Where is the compression happening?** Is the data transfered over the internet to the cloud, and then compressed. Or does it get compressed on-prem by the self-hosted integration runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the compression happening?

The compression happens on the self-hosted Integration Runtime.

If it is a [staged copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#how-staged-copy-works), the IR will compress the data when writing to the intermediate blob storage account.  And if it's not a staged copy, the IR writes the files directly to ADLS.